# How to show values inside countries in JQVmap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqvmap

I'm making a strategy game like Risk (but simpler). I'm doing the representation with `JQVmap` and I want to show inside the country the units that country have inside. Just show a number. Any ideas?
I tried with `onLabelShow` but it displays only when mouse the mouse hovers over the country and the info is not inside the country borders.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by making a function that appends divs to the div with ID `vmap`. The bad thing is that you have to get the coordinates of each state.
The div must be positioned 'absolute'.  For example:

```
$("#vmap").append("<div class='info' style='top: " + coord[1] +"px; left: "+coord[0]+"px'>"+ "text you want to show" + "</div>");
```